# Python: How to print out a certain range of the alphabet

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Battleship grid, with numbers on the left and the letters on top. I'm confused on how you would print out a certain amount of letters and add them on with python. I'm an extremely new beginner when it comes to Python.

For example:

```
    def displayGrid(Rows,Columns):
        output = '| '
        for title in range(97,110):
            output = output + chr(title)
            output = output + ' |'
        print(output)

        for row in range(Rows):
            output = str(row + 1) + '| '
            for col in range(Columns):
                output = output + " | "
            print(output)

    Rows = int(input("Number of rows you want? \n"))
    Columns = int(input("Number of columns you want? \n"))

    displayGrid(Rows, Columns)
```

I want it so the number of Columns is the number of letters that it prints out but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop (`for title in range(97,110):`) will always have a fixed length (of 110-97=13 elements), so you'll always end up with the same first line, regardless of how many columns you want.

Try something like `for title in range(97, 97+Columns):`

Comment: Right before you said this, I fixed it. I'm baffled on how clueless I am. Sorry for saying this needless question.

Comment: Welcome to Mondays. :)

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
    for title in range(97,110):
        output = output + chr(title)
        output = output + ' |'
    print(output)
```

by

```
output = " |" +"|".join([chr(i) for i in range(97,97+Columns)])
print(output)
```

Comment: I would use that, but I haven't learned it yet and I value what I'm supposed to use first and not use needless things that might confuse me later. But that is just my way of learning xd.

Comment: @Mvpgman1425 I do agree that using code you don't understand is a bad idea but the is no sorcery in this

Comment: I just tried this and it causes  some unevenness. It also causes problems with the layout of the grid. When I further learn this, I will try doing it. Thanks for giving me some tips though. :)

Comment: @Mvpgman1425 for the unevenness just add a space before the |

Comment: Still has a problem with the layout.   http://prntscr.com/ac85v0 http://prntscr.com/ac85xj

Comment: @Mvpgman1425 see my edit, we need to add an extra space and | for the row numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can access the lowercase letters through

```
from string import lowercase
```

And a clean way to achieve your string would be:

```
result = "| " + " | ".join(lowercase[0:size]) + " |"
```

Answer (score -1):

Few tips -

1. When you have an iteratable you want to print and join with certain delimiter you can use join - 
   `'|'.join(["a", "b", "c"])
   a|b|c`
2. `from string import lowercase` will give you a string (which you can iterate on) all the lower case letters.
3. Check python itertools - https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html